# Angular Filter Dot Notation

Tags: angularjs

There are a lot of questions similar to this where the thing being filtered in an `ng-repeat` is a property of an object, but my question is different. My filter itself is applying to an array collection of objects with nested properties, and the dot notation isn't working.

Like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-4"><div id="searchContainer" style="position:relative;text-align:center;">
<label for="search-input"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></label>
    <input id="search-input" ng-model="userInputSearch" placeholder="Student Name" autocorrect="off" tabindex="1">
</div></div>
<div class="col-sm-4"><div id="searchContainer" style="position:relative;text-align:center;">
<label for="search-input"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></label>
    <input id="search-input" ng-model="audioInputSearch" placeholder="Audio Name" autocorrect="off" tabindex="1">
</div></div>
<!-- Search Bars Above, Ng-Repeat Below -->
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="a in audio | filter:{ uploader: userInputSearch } | filter: {audio.name: audioInputSearch} track by $index ">
<div class="tile nobig @{{colors[$index]}}">
@{{a.audio.name}}</br>
Uploaded By <a class="white" target="_self" href="http://example.com/user/@{{a.audio.user_id}}">@{{a.uploader}}</a>
</br>
Length: @{{a.audio.Length|HHMMSS}}</br>
<i class="fa ear fa-play"></i>
</br></br>
</div>
</div>
```

The array of objects I am repeating over:

```
[{"audio":{"id":"43","user_id":"74","name":"controlla","url":"controlla.wav","Length":"234","LengthD":"short","ForTask":"True","created_at":"2016-06-21 13:06:06","updated_at":"2016-06-21 13:06:06"},"uploader":"Summer"},{"audio":{"id":"52","user_id":"74","name":"roywoodshowifeel","url":"roywoodshowifeel-56e65.wav","Length":"225","LengthD":"short","ForTask":"True","created_at":"2016-06-21 22:11:15","updated_at":"2016-06-21 22:11:15"},"uploader":"Summer"},{"audio":{"id":"53","user_id":"74","name":"bodman","url":"bodman-fc378.wav","Length":"194","LengthD":"short","ForTask":"True","created_at":"2016-06-22 00:05:41","updated_at":"2016-06-22 00:05:41"},"uploader":"Summer"},{"audio":{"id":"54","user_id":"74","name":"shake070sundaynight","url":"shake070sundaynight-6119e.wav","Length":"274","LengthD":"short","ForTask":"True","created_at":"2016-06-22 00:09:05","updated_at":"2016-06-22 00:09:05"},"uploader":"Summer"},{"audio":{"id":"55","user_id":"74","name":"audio1","url":"audio1-f895c.wav","Length":"121","LengthD":"short","ForTask":"True","created_at":"2016-06-22 01:45:39","updated_at":"2016-06-22 01:45:39"},"uploader":"Summer"},{"audio":{"id":"56","user_id":"74","name":"audio2","url":"audio2.wav","Length":"726","LengthD":"short","ForTask":"True","created_at":"2016-06-22 01:46:05","updated_at":"2016-06-22 01:46:05"},"uploader":"Summer"},{"audio":{"id":"59","user_id":"74","name":"loner","url":"loner-2070b.wav","Length":"209","LengthD":"short","ForTask":"True","created_at":"2016-06-22 01:57:51","updated_at":"2016-06-22 01:57:51"},"uploader":"Summer"},{"audio":{"id":"60","user_id":"74","name":"comeandseeme","url":"comeandseeme-41399.wav","Length":"232","LengthD":"short","ForTask":"True","created_at":"2016-06-22 01:58:28","updated_at":"2016-06-22 01:58:28"},"uploader":"Summer"},{"audio":{"id":"61","user_id":"74","name":"loner","url":"loner-1d416.wav","Length":"209","LengthD":"short","ForTask":"True","created_at":"2016-06-22 01:58:30","updated_at":"2016-06-22 01:58:30"},"uploader":"Summer"},{"audio":{"id":"63","user_id":"74","name":"comeandseeme","url":"comeandseeme-d41e7.wav","Length":"232","LengthD":"short","ForTask":"True","created_at":"2016-06-22 02:03:02","updated_at":"2016-06-22 02:03:02"},"uploader":"Summer"},{"audio":{"id":"64","user_id":"74","name":"nopolice","url":"nopolice-0b883.wav","Length":"258","LengthD":"short","ForTask":"True","created_at":"2016-06-22 02:12:57","updated_at":"2016-06-22 02:12:57"},"uploader":"Summer"},{"audio":{"id":"65","user_id":"74","name":"ovo","url":"ovo.wav","Length":"4080","LengthD":"long","ForTask":"True","created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"},"uploader":"Summer"}]
```

So how do I get it to filter by `audio.name` without throwing an unexpected `.` error?

Comment: what is this `@` in front of every `{{}}`?

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe sorry, that's because I'm rendering the view with Laravel and it needs that so the Angular can run uninterrupted (Laravel also uses `{{}}`)

Comment: Like this : {audio: {name: audioInputSearch}}

Comment: @Silvinus thank you!